# What is the correct way to send an HDLC frame to an HID USB device using Java (particularly the hid4java library)?

Tags: java, usb, byte, hid

I am trying to send an HDLC frame (which envelopes a command) to an HID usb device using java.
I am using the hid4java library.
I can use the library to list out all devices and select the concerned device I want to work with.
With this library, I can also open the device to establish a communication pipeline.
I am sure I have constructed the hdlc frame properly and I can post the code later if that would help derive an answer.

Here is the code showing what I have tried. Before this, I have also attempted using the sendFeatureReport() method. My main issue is I do not know how to get the reportID of my attached USB device. Also, if there is another method I am meant to use to write the hdlc frame, please feel free to let me know as well!
Lastly, I am not averse to trying another java library as long as it has good documentation!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    HidServices services = HidManager.getHidServices();
    List<HidDevice> devices = services.getAttachedHidDevices();

    //list the kestrel
    HidDevice kestrel = null;
    for(HidDevice d : devices) {
        if(d.getProductId() == 0x892) { //Dynamically do this
            kestrel = d;
            System.out.println(d);
        }
    }

    //open the device
    boolean isOpen = kestrel.open();
    System.out.println("isOpen -- " + isOpen);

    //build hdlc frame
    byte[] command = {(byte)0x04, (byte)0x80, (byte)0x7E, (byte)0x28, (byte)0x7D, (byte)0x48}; //test
    HDLC_Frame frame = new HDLC_Frame();
    byte[] finalCommand = frame.transformToHDLC(command);

    for(int i = 0; i<finalCommand.length; i++){
        System.out.println(finalCommand[i]);
    }

    //send hdlc frame        
    //this fails. I believe the problem is either with the reportID or the FCS in the HDLC frame
    System.out.println(kestrel.write(finalCommand, finalCommand.length, (byte) 0x00));

    //This is what the hdlc frame is meant to look like after transformation, and this is
    //what my method returns. So I know the transformToHDLC() method I implemented is correct!
    byte[] resultFrame = {(byte)0x7E, (byte)0x04, (byte)0x80, (byte)0x7D, (byte)0x5E, (byte)0x28, 
        (byte)0x7D, (byte)0x5D, (byte)0x48, (byte)0x78, (byte)0xD2, (byte)0x7E};

    System.out.println("------------------------------------");
    for(int i = 0; i<resultFrame.length; i++){
        System.out.println(resultFrame[i]);
    }            
}
```

The write() method returns -1. And according to the doc, that means there was an error. If there is no error, it is meant to return the number of bytes written!

Comment: If it helps, I am on a windows computer

Comment: You can find out the report ids (if any) by capturing a packet trace as you plug in the USB device. Wireshark can do this. Look for the incoming HID Report Descriptor in the captured trace.